# LinearLayout color borders

Tags: android, border, android-linearlayout

I want to show all cells in the LinearLayout like in this widget

[image: Google Sample Widget]

This image taken from the app widget tutorial in android developer site. Google explained that is LinearLayout but did not explain how to to the gray lines between the buttons.

How can I split widget like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use several things here:

1. A simple View with a background color of the separator (1 or 2 width, height is fill_parent)
2. An ImageView with the source set as the separator's image (1 or 2 width, height is fill_parent)
3. Extend the view and draw a separator with a canvas (probably overkill for what you need)

Hope this helps :)